# convert a nested array to a specific select box in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a nested array like this :

```
$categories = [
  ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'TV & Home Theather'],
  ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Tablets & E-Readers'],
  ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Computers', 'children' => [
    ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'Laptops', 'children' => [
      ['id' => 5, 'name' => 'PC Laptops'],
      ['id' => 6, 'name' => 'Macbooks (Air/Pro)']
    ]],
    ['id' => 7, 'name' => 'Desktops'],
    ['id' => 8, 'name' => 'Monitors']
  ]],
  ['id' => 9, 'name' => 'Cell Phones']
];
```

I'm looking for a way in larvel or PHP to convert that into a nested combo box like this:

```
 <option value="1">TV & Home Theather</option>
 <option value="2">Tablets & E-Readers</option>
 <option value="3">Computers</option>
 <option value="4">Computers >> Laptops </option>
 <option value="5">Computers >> Laptops >> PC Laptops</option>
 <option value="6">Computers >> Laptops >> Macbooks (Air/Pro) </option>
 <option value="7">Computers >> Desktops </option>
 <option value="8">Computers >> Monitors </option>
 <option value="9">Cell Phones</option>
```

Means that I want it looks like this :

[image]

Comment: you need `ul` unordedrlist which consists of `li` s  not select boxs right ?

Comment: show us your blade code?? you could loop 3 times to have this result but may be need some changes in your view\

Comment: @MahdiYounesi, I updated my question, in fact I do not want to create a list , it was a sample to show what I want to do

Comment: Have you considered using `<optgroup>` tag? It would look way cleaner and organised

Comment: you want to build a tree, if categories were a collection containing all collections with it schildren which you need a `parent_id` field, I already have the answer! because I have done it iny my projects

Comment: `optgroup` can not get any id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to implement this using pure PHP with a recursive function...

First we define the array of categories:

```
$categories = [
  ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'TV & Home Theather'],
  ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Tablets & E-Readers'],
  ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Computers', 'children' => [
    ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'Laptops', 'children' => [
      ['id' => 5, 'name' => 'PC Laptops'],
      ['id' => 6, 'name' => 'Macbooks (Air/Pro)']
    ]],
    ['id' => 7, 'name' => 'Desktops'],
    ['id' => 8, 'name' => 'Monitors']
  ]],
  ['id' => 9, 'name' => 'Cell Phones']
];
```

Next we define a recursive function that will pass category titles for parents:

```
function printCats($categories, $parent = NULL) {
    while ($category = array_shift($categories)) {
        $catName = ($parent ? $parent.' &gt;&gt; ' : '').$category['name'];
        print("<option value='{$category['id']}'>{$catName}</option>\n");
        if (isset($category['children']))
            printCats($category['children'], $catName);
    }
}
```

And finally, invocation, passing the category tree:

```
printCats($categories);
```

Output:

```
<option value='1'>TV & Home Theather</option>
<option value='2'>Tablets & E-Readers</option>
<option value='3'>Computers</option>
<option value='4'>Computers &gt;&gt; Laptops</option>
<option value='5'>Computers &gt;&gt; Laptops &gt;&gt; PC Laptops</option>
<option value='6'>Computers &gt;&gt; Laptops &gt;&gt; Macbooks (Air/Pro)</option>
<option value='7'>Computers &gt;&gt; Desktops</option>
<option value='8'>Computers &gt;&gt; Monitors</option>
<option value='9'>Cell Phones</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not looking to implement this yourself, I've used this package in the past.

https://github.com/atayahmet/laravel-nestable

That will take a nested array/collection and convert it to an HTML list. For the documentation, here is an example of the output:

```
<select name="categories">
    <option value="1">T-shirts</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">  Red T-shirts</option>
    <option value="3">  Black T-shirts</option>

    <option value="4">Sweaters</option>
    <option value="5">  Red Sweaters</option>
    <option value="6">  Blue Sweaters</option>
</select>
```

It's support for macros is a nice feature too, allowing you to easily integrate routes.

Comment: I'using https://github.com/etrepat/baum and in fact that array I shown in my question is an export from categories tree saved in DB. But now I want to convert it to desired select options

Comment: Sure, that package is a great choice for nested set implementation. However, the link I provided is specifically for menu/category creation. You can use both together without issue. Since you have your tree structure, simple add the trait this package provides and create your menu. Easy goes it.